# How to use the 'key' in flutter's method?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34bHT.png)

That method in picture that makes an error, It's called from other file. About that, Flutter required a parameter 'key', so I made it. but makes an error again like below.

Error: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'.

Conclusively what's after 'key:' instead of null?

'''

```
SavingAccountCard(
                  color: Color(0xffF1A8AF), key: null,
```

'''

Comment: what is `SavingAccountCard` in your case

Comment: Can you share SavingAccountCard parameters and how those are declared?

Answer (score 2):

Key is a unique identifier of the widget.
There are different types of keys:

- ValueKey
- ObjectKey
- UniqueKey
- GlobalKey

You may be able to remove the required Key from your class, but if it's required and  used there you can just use ValueKey('someUniqueIdByYou').
so the code would be:

```
SavingAccountCard(
  color: Color(0xffF1A8AF), 
  key: ValueKey<String>('AccountCard'),
),
```